# Swing JLabel: Force repaint()

Tags: java, swing, components, repaint

I am trying to repaint a JLabel dynamically and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. The code below will do as expected once I resize the screen but will not execute the code by itself.

The JLabel has a little circle to the left which is drawn in the border region to the left of the text. The color of the circle should change as a function of the health of an FTP connection (not shown). The thread monitoring the FTP connection calls the `setStatus(int)` method when the health changes.

The circle is painted during initialization of the JLabel, and I am trying to re-execute this code using `repaint()`.

**EDIT:** I have also tried playing with `revalidate()`, `invalidate()`, and `validate()` to no avail.

**EDIT:** Thanks for pointing that out, I started by using `paintComponent()` and changed to `paint()` when that didn't work. So no glory for giving that as an answer (sorry, take it up with the Oracle)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import com.my.package.io.ftp.FTPConnectionListenable;

class StatusLabel extends JLabel implements FTPConnectionListenable {

    private Integer status;

    // Constructor
    StatusLabel(final String text) {
        super(text);
        setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fillArc(0, this.getHeight()/4, 8, 8, 0, 360);
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus (final int status) {
        this.status = status;
        if (status !=0) 
        repaint(); // Doesn't work :(
    }

    private Color getColor () {
        switch (status) {
        case FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_OK:
            return Color.GREEN;
        case FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_WARNING:
            return Color.ORANGE;
        case FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_ERROR:
            return Color.RED;
        default: 
            return Color.PINK;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommen you use an `enum` rather than an `interface` for `FTPConnectionListenable`.

Answer (score 4):

Klong, your code works for me, so likely you have a bug elsewhere.  How I tested it,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


class StatusLabel extends JLabel implements FTPConnectionListenable {

    private Integer status;

    // Constructor
    StatusLabel(final String text) {
        super(text);
        setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fillArc(0, this.getHeight()/4, 8, 8, 0, 360);
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus (final int status) {
        this.status = status;
        if (status !=0) 
        repaint(); 
    }

    private Color getColor () {
        switch (status) {
        case FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_OK:
            return Color.GREEN;
        case FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_WARNING:
            return Color.ORANGE;
        case FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_ERROR:
            return Color.RED;
        default: 
            return Color.PINK;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      final StatusLabel statusLabel = new StatusLabel("Foo");
      statusLabel.setStatus(FTPConnectionListenable.STATUS_OK);
      new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
         int counter = 0;
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter++;
            counter %= 4;
            statusLabel.setStatus(counter);
         }
      }).start();

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, statusLabel);
   }
}

interface FTPConnectionListenable {

   static final int STATUS_ERROR = 0;
   static final int STATUS_WARNING = 1;
   static final int STATUS_OK = 2;
   void setStatus(int status);

}
```

By the way, that's one *small* arc.

Answer (score 3):

You should override paintComponent and call super method before doing anything else:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(getColor());
    g.fillArc(0, this.getHeight()/4, 8, 8, 0, 360);

}
```

Comment: @klong: "but it doesn't work" tells us nothing. What happens when you try it? Errors? No display? It does back flips?

Comment: @Heisenburg The reason for calling repaint() explicitly is to have the paintComponent method executed with a new value of status. What doesn't work is that the circle doesn't change color. The only way I can force the paintComponent to execute with the new status is to resize the screen.

Comment: @klonq: sorry.. I didn't see that method. Let me think a little bit what could be the problem.

Comment: @klong, you've got a bug elsewhere because your code works fine for me.

Comment: @klong: check that status value is effectively different from 0

Answer (score 2):

First thing that I notice is that you should be overriding `paintComponent`, not `paint`.

Comment: @klonq, when I have more time, I'll take a closer look at this. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Rather thanoverriding `paint()`, you probably just want to override `paintComponent()`.

Also, the call to `super.paint(g)` should be done at the beginning of your method, otherwise any painting you perform may be overwritten by the `JLabel` own painting.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't repaint then the problem is likely that you are doing your FTP connection on the Event Dispatch Thread which is blocking and preventing the GUI from repainting.

You need to use a separate Thread for the FTP connection. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and a solution using a `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

Status needs to be volatile to make sure the Event Dispatch Thread sees the new value set by the ftp thread.